# Android Layout best practices - edit and display content

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm setting up layouts for my content and am unsure how to approach toggling between `edit mode` and `display mode`.

Do I

1. Create two completely different layouts (e.g., person_fragment_display / person_fragment_edit),

or

2. Create one layout and "VISIBLE" or "GONE" my control views based on mode (i.e., show a first_name_textView in display mode and first_name_editText in edit mode)

Neither approach is difficult but I'd like to know if there are any performance, layout complexities or other issues to consider?

Comment: both are fine but if it was up to me, i would create another fragment, why i create two different layouts in one layout? its not html tho that your images takes time to be displayed and what so on, as long as you keep your code clean in your activity, then there will be no issue regard the performance of two normal fragments.

Comment: Thank you k0sh.  A little way down the multi-layout path I started to see unneeded complexity I was adding.  Going to go with your recommendation.

Comment: There is also an element called `ViewSwitcher` which lets you toggle between two view elements: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html